# should duplicate answers be marked as such if old?

Tags: discussion

For [Can't mkdir events No space left on device - EC2 Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188511/cant-mkdir-events-no-space-left-on-device-ec2-linux)

many distros **now** consider `btrfs` to be stable. back when the original answer was posted, I would not have suggested `btrfs` but today it seems to be widely suggested (and I am using it).

What is the general way on SE to give a different answer when the referred thread is too old?

Answer (score 1):

That depends a bit on whether there is a chance that the "old" question will get a different accepted answer, and that has to do with the availability (i.e. how recent was the OP active).

If the information in the "old" question is blatantly outdated, but the OP of the question is not active, then a correct answer there is unlikely going to get noticed. In that case giving an up-to-date answer to the new question might be more appropriate, and the old question could be marked as duplicate (preferably after the answer is accepted, but IIRC at least it needs to have an upvote to be allowed to be the duplicate).