# handling years old duplicate

Tags: feature-request

I came upon this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377359/how-to-use-ocr-from-the-command-line-in-linux)  which is marked as [duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548/ocr-on-linux-systems).

However, earliest answer is 6 years old, things might have change since them. I feel there should be a way to tell apart *intemporal* duplicate (difference between tty/console/shell, for instance), and duplicate where things change.

I voted to leave open, yet are there any other mechanism I'm unaware of to solve this issue ?

(my question was [asked](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/should-duplicate-answers-be-marked-as-such-if-old) before)

Comment: Couldn't old questions (assuming they're still on-topic) get new answers?

Answer (score 1):

Bounties:

> [image]